# A contradiction to $C_c^\infty \subset H^1$ not dense?

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

Now we know that $C_c^\infty(\Omega) \subset H^1(\Omega)$ is NOT dense.

We also know that (eg. from Lions' and Magenes) that if $V \subset H \subset V'$ is Hilbert triple,
$$\mathcal{D}(0,T;V) \subset W(0,T)\quad\text{ is dense},$$
where $\mathcal{D}(0,T;V)$ is the space of infinitely-differentiable compactly supported functions with values in $V$ and $W(0,T) = \{ u \in L^2(0,T;V) : u' \in L^2(0,T;V')\}$

If we let $V=H=\mathbb{R}$ and $\Omega=(0,T)$, then doesn't this latter result contradict our first result??

Comment: Maybe you  misunderstood their claim. What is the exact reference?

Comment: It's http://rd.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-642-65161-8/page/1, Theorem 2.1 I believe. However, I think this is what is meant: instead of $\mathcal{D}(0,T;V)$ it should be $\mathcal{D}([0,T];V)$.

Comment: So basically then it means $C^\infty(0,T;V) \subset \mathcal{D}([0,T];V)$ I think..